# Annotation does not work correctly in Okular

Tags: pdf, okular

I hava [a pdf file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/annotatepdf/2.pdf).

In okular 0.17.2 under Ubuntu 12.04, I have found two problems:

- added inline note (by F6, and then 2)  will be rotated 90 degree counterclockwise.
- added underline (by F6, and then 8)  doesn't show.

See the resulted pdf file [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/annotatepdf/2annotated.pdf).

Is this some problem with the pdf file, or with okular?

Thanks.

Comment: Try installing a newer version of Okular. There's already version 0.20. Check if there's a ppa with a ewer version.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with various PDF readers in ubuntu .
some give annotation and it is not saved in file directly,uses some mechanism.
Thats why your notes,highlights done in okular cannot be viewed in another PDF viewer.
The best way is to install Foxit reader along with wine.

As of my knowledge there is no native application in ubuntu that can annotate PDF's

Comment: Thanks. Heard that Foxit viewer has or had a linux version, Is it not as good as its windows version?

Comment: The Linux version of Foxit is not the equivalent to its Windows brother and does not permit annotations.

Answer (score 0):

A newer Okular version (20.12.3 in my case) annotates correctly and the annotations can be viewed by any other external programs.